# Unity Serialize IConvertible variable

Tags: unity

How can i Serialize IConvertible variable to show up in the inspector? As it now, i can only see the string name. But not the value.

E.g adding CStat

```
item.AddCStats("description", "This a long ranged boosted weapon.");
item.AddCStats("attack", 10);
item.AddCStats("speed", 50f);
item.AddCStats("unique", true)
```

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Item : ISerializationCallbackReceiver
{
    [SerializeField]
    public int id = 0;
    [SerializeField]
    public int amount = 1;
    [SerializeField]
    public List<CStats> cstats = new List<CStats>();
    public Dictionary<name, IConvertible> cstatsDictionary = new Dictionary<name, IConvertible>();

    public Item(int id, int amount)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public void AddCStats<T>(string name, T value) where T : IConvertible
    {
        if (!cstatsDictionary.TryGetValue(name, out _))
        {
            cstatsDictionary.Add(name, value);
        }
        else
        {
            cstatsDictionary[name] = value;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < cstats.Count; i++)
        {
            if cstats[i].name == name)
            {
                cstats[i].value = value;
                return;
            }
        }

        cstats.Add(new CStats(name, value));
    }

    public T GetCStat<T>(string name) where T : IConvertible
    {
        return cstatsDictionary.TryGetValue(name, out IConvertible value) ? ConvertToType<T>(value) : default;
    }

    public void OnAfterDeserialize()
    {
        cstatsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, IConvertible>();
        for (int i = 0; i < cstats.Count; i++)
        {
            cstatsDictionary.Add(cstats[i].name, cstats[i].value);
        }
    }

    public void OnBeforeSerialize()
    {
    }

    private T ConvertToType<T>(IConvertible value) where T : IConvertible
    {
        return (T)value.ToType(typeof(T), null);
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class CStats
{
    [SerializeField]
    public string name = String.empty;
    [SerializeField]
    public IConvertible value = null;

    public CStats(string name, IConvertible value)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unity's serializer doesn't handle polymorphic types well. Can you tell us more about how this value is used? We may be able to suggest other ways to achieve that end, that will play nicer with Unity's serialization and inspector tools.

Comment: Well why i want it be generic. Since it should be able to store string, int, double, float, long and etc...

I would like be add a new CStat, with custom string name and a generic value. For e.g if CStat name is description, then value shall be string. While CStats name is Attack, then the value will be a int

Comment: And you have to process these as a mixed bag that could contain anything? That sounds slow and like a recipe for a lot of boxing & unboxing overhead. If you made a `Stat<ValueType>` class, you could specialize it to a concrete type like `StringStat : Stat<String>` and get proper serialization and editing of individual stats or collections of the same type of stat. For mixed bags though, I think the best you can do is a discriminated union, which has additional overhead from being able to support any type in the same container.

Comment: Sounds great, can you provide a example hos the setup would look like?

Comment: Which one? I'll need a bit more context of how these are used in your Unity scripts to give a good-quality answer.

Comment: I understand, i've updated my first post. Hopefully you can guide me to the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using this `CStat` type purely for serialization, and at runtime everything uses the versions you've decoded into your dictionary.

With that in mind, we can set up a type that always serializes its value down to a string, but remembers its assigned type so it can be decoded to the appropriate type in your dictionary:

```
[System.Serializable]
public struct SerializedStat
{
    public enum ValueType {
        String,
        Integer,
        Long,
        Float,
        Double,
        Boolean
    }

    public string name;

    [SerializeField]
    ValueType _type;

    [SerializeField]
    string _serializedValue;

    public SerializedStat(string name, string value) {
        this.name = name;
        _type = ValueType.String;
        _serializedValue = value;
    }

    public System.IConvertible GetValue() {
        switch(_type) {
            case ValueType.String: return _serializedValue;
            case ValueType.Integer: return GetIntValue();
            case ValueType.Long: return GetLongValue();
            case ValueType.Float: return GetFloatValue();
            case ValueType.Double: return GetDoubleValue();
            case ValueType.Boolean: return GetBoolValue();            
            default: return null;
        }
    }

    public string GetStringValue() { return _serializedValue; }
    public int GetIntValue() { return int.Parse(_serializedValue); }
    public long GetLongValue() { return long.Parse(_serializedValue); }
    public float GetFloatValue() { return float.Parse(_serializedValue); }
    public double GetDoubleValue() { return double.Parse(_serializedValue); }
    public bool GetBoolValue() { return bool.Parse(_serializedValue); }


    public void SetValue(string value) {
        _type = ValueType.String;
        _serializedValue = value;
    }

    public void SetValue(int value) {
        _type = ValueType.Integer;
        _serializedValue = value.ToString();
    }

    public void SetValue(long value) {
        _type = ValueType.Long;
        _serializedValue = value.ToString();
    }

    public void SetValue(float value) {
        _type = ValueType.Float;
        _serializedValue = value.ToString("R"); // "R" means "Round-trip-able"
    }

    public void SetValue(double value) {
        _type = ValueType.Double;
        _serializedValue = value.ToString("R");
    }

    public void SetValue(bool value) {
        _type = ValueType.Boolean;
        _serializedValue = value.ToString();
    }
}
```

This is a bit messy, but it lets the Unity serializer work with types it knows what to do with, and we can convert to `IConvertible` to add them to your dictionary by calling `GetValue()` after deserializing.

We can put a custom property drawer script in an Editor folder, to allow us to author these various types in the Inspector:

[image: Editor Preview]

(Disclaimer: it's been a while since I wrote property drawers - I think this one still needs a bit of work to support multi-object editing and other such cases)

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(SerializedStat))]
public class SerializedStatDrawer : PropertyDrawer {
    // Draw the property inside the given 


    public override float GetPropertyHeight(SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label) {
        return EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight * (property.isExpanded ? 2 : 1);
    }

    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label) {

        float valueWidth = position.width - EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth;

        var nameProperty = property.FindPropertyRelative("name");
        var valueProperty = property.FindPropertyRelative("_serializedValue");
        var typeProperty = property.FindPropertyRelative("_type");
        var currentType = (SerializedStat.ValueType)typeProperty.enumValueIndex;

        var fieldRect = position;
        fieldRect.height = EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;
        fieldRect.width = EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth;

        string caption = property.isExpanded ? "" : nameProperty.stringValue;
        property.isExpanded = EditorGUI.Foldout(fieldRect, property.isExpanded, caption, true);

        if (property.isExpanded) {
            // Name Field
            fieldRect.width = position.width;
            EditorGUI.PropertyField(fieldRect, nameProperty);

            // Type Field            
            fieldRect.y += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;
            fieldRect.width = EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth;
            var selectedType = (SerializedStat.ValueType)EditorGUI.EnumPopup(fieldRect, currentType);            

            // If the user changes the type, reset the value to something valid for that type.
            // Here I just nuke everything to default, but you could try converting the previous value as close as possible.
            if (selectedType != currentType) {
                typeProperty.enumValueIndex = (int)selectedType;
                switch(selectedType) {
                    case SerializedStat.ValueType.Integer:
                    case SerializedStat.ValueType.Long:
                    case SerializedStat.ValueType.Float:
                    case SerializedStat.ValueType.Double:
                        valueProperty.stringValue = "0";
                        break;
                    case SerializedStat.ValueType.Boolean:
                        valueProperty.stringValue = "False";
                        break;
                    case SerializedStat.ValueType.String:
                        valueProperty.stringValue = "default";
                        break;
                }
                currentType = selectedType;
            }


        }

        // Value Field
        fieldRect.x += EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth;
        fieldRect.width = valueWidth;
        string value = valueProperty.stringValue;
        switch (currentType) {
            case SerializedStat.ValueType.Integer:
                valueProperty.stringValue = EditorGUI.IntField(fieldRect, int.Parse(value)).ToString();
                break;
            case SerializedStat.ValueType.Long:
                valueProperty.stringValue = EditorGUI.LongField(fieldRect, long.Parse(value)).ToString();
                break;
            case SerializedStat.ValueType.Float:
                valueProperty.stringValue = EditorGUI.FloatField(fieldRect, float.Parse(value)).ToString("R");
                break;
            case SerializedStat.ValueType.Double:
                valueProperty.stringValue = EditorGUI.DoubleField(fieldRect, double.Parse(value)).ToString("R");
                break;
            case SerializedStat.ValueType.Boolean:
                valueProperty.stringValue = EditorGUI.Toggle(fieldRect, bool.Parse(value)).ToString();
                break;
            case SerializedStat.ValueType.String:
                valueProperty.stringValue = EditorGUI.TextField(fieldRect, value);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is god like! I really appreciate this, such a learning curve i got. As you metion, i made cheap hacky solutions to serialize.

Comment: Sorry to bother again. I got everything up and running. It's awesome that it convert to the proper value from the inspector. But for e.g i would like add a cStat through code. Then the type it Will show up as string in the inspector.

Comment: That's fine, you can call SetValue on it with your type of choice and it will take on that type. Or you can add constructors for other types too.

Comment: Oh i see what you mean, is it still possible pass a generic value? So i can use AddCStats(name, T value)? Or will i end up like before, that it cant be serialized

Comment: You need to know the type you want to store in the variable at some time. Maybe not at creation, maybe in a fix-up phase afterward. But at some point your program says "This is a stat I want to assign a float to". At that point you can call `SetValue(0.0f)` to force the stat to float type.